# Can sigil-less variables or constants be interpolated?

Tags: raku, string-interpolation

Although I have found no documentation for it, apparently you can interpolate sigilless variables and constants surrounding them by {}:

```
constant ⲧ = " " xx 4;
say "{ⲧ}Tabbed"; # OUTPUT: «       Tabbed␤»
```

Apparently, you need to [use the `:c` adverb to do so](https://docs.perl6.org/language/quoting#Literal_strings:_Q).

```
say q:c"π is {π}"; # OUTPUT: «π is 3.141592653589793␤»
```

But that is only within if `q` (and derived) quotes are used. Is this simply an undocumented feature, or is something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are all exactly identical

```perl6
          "a $b {$c}"
qq        "a $b {$c}"
Q :qq     "a $b {$c}"
Q :double "a $b {$c}"

Q :b :s :a :h :c :f "a $b {$c}"
Q :backslash :scalar :array :hash :closure :function "a $b {$c}"
```

In order for the string literal parser to see `{}` as creating a closure it needs the closure feature to be enabled.

One of the things that the `:qq` / `:double` enables is `:c` / `:closure`.

You can also disable it with `:!closure`.

```perl6
say qq :!closure "{ 1 + 2 }";
# { 1 + 2 }
```

That is it starts with `:qq` / `:double` semantics and turns off `:closure` semantics.

---

[Here](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/1c101a04f92ed199eec62cc31a6b2ffba874a8cd/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L5298) is where the `qq` feature is defined in Rakudo

```perl6
role qq does b1 does c1 does s1 does a1 does h1 does f1 {
    token starter { \" }
    token stopper { \" }
    method tweak_q($v) { self.panic("Too late for :q") }
    method tweak_qq($v) { self.panic("Too late for :qq") }
}
```

`b1` enables backslash
`c1` enables closure
`s1` enables scalar
`a1` enables array
`h1` enables hash
`f1` enables function

---

It is documented, and you provided a link to the documentation.
Perhaps it could be made more clear that:

- `""` is short for `qq ""`
- `qq ""` is short for `Q :qq ""` / `Q :double ""`
- `:qq` / `:double` is short for all of `:backslash` `:closure` `:scalar` `:array` `:hash` `:function`.

Also it may be worth adding examples for all of those features.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see it as an undocumented feature but rather as inherent to the design of the existing features.

A *double* quote string (`"..."`) interpolates expressions of the form `{...}` as code. So it just works.

A `q` quote, by default, is like a *single* quote string (`'...'`). So, by default, it does *not* interpolate expressions of the form `{...}`. But if you add the `c` adverb it then *does* interpolate these `c`ode blocks, so the same thing that works in double quote strings by default also works with `q:c`.

Or maybe *I*'m missing something. We seem to be roughly complementary on our blindnesses. Together we've maybe got 50/50 vision, whatever that might mean. :)

Comment: If you have 50/50 vision, it means you see at 50' what a normal person would see at 50'.

Comment: @ikegami I see 2 trees and the gardens of neighbors' houses. (Perhaps you meant 50/50 vision as a static type rather than a dynamic value but I suffer from TDD so feel compelled to provide a `*.defined` value.) My guess is a normal person would see the same things but there's only a 50/50 chance they'd say so, so I still don't know if I'm hyperopic and JJ's myopic, or we're both presbyopic, or it's just me. Fortunately my neighbor Brad has deployed their million/1 mental acuity once more so I'll quit piling on my obscure 50/50 humor while I can still fool myself into thinking it's visionary...

Comment: Well thanks for that. I will say that you also have posts which are better than I would have written.

Comment: Hi Brad. I freely spend absurd amounts of time without regard for the question or situation warranting the effort. For a couple years I'd see you write just a comment with absolute economy of words and often not bother writing an answer even though you'd absolutely nailed the key issue. I'm glad to see you more frequently expand into answers, and now more frequently essentially perfect answers. I can no longer make up my mind whether I find more remarkable your mastery of P6, or the general mental skill of knowing what you know and don't know, or your writing skills. Either way, I'm learning.